# onClick function is called for every input change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

Im trying to post to a local server using an onclick function, but every time the input field changes here, it calls the function, leading to unecessary function calls, and I can't figure out why it is being called here.

```
const testPost = () => {
  console.log("Clicked!")
  Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/', {testName: "albumName"})
    .then(() => {
      console.log('successful insert')
    });
};

function App() {

  const [albumName, setAlbumName] = useState('')

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <input type="text" name="albumName" onChange={(e) => {
          setAlbumName(e.target.value)
        }}/>
        <button onClick={testPost()}>Submit</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lose the (), So it’s just `{testPost}`.

If you do `testPost()` you’re calling/executing `testPost` every time the component renders. As soon as that line is encountered by the JS interpreter, it runs the function.

With `onClick`, you only want to pass the reference of the function to be called **on click**. So just use `testPost`.

Also with react, every time the state changes within a component, it re-renders the whole component, so that’s why your function is being called every time there is an input change.